# Long Rails 6 migration printout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-migrations

I upgraded from rails 5.2.3 to 6.1.0 and noticed that my migration log for add_reference has changed.

With Rails 5 it simply had:

```
-- add_reference(:categories, :user, {:foreign_key=>true})
  -> 0.0063s
```

With Rails 6 I get this:

```
-- update_table_definition(:categories, ...)
   -> 0.0001s
-- add_column("categories", "user_id", :bigint, {})
   -> 0.0027s
-- add_index("categories", ["user_id"], {})
   -> 0.0041s
-- add_foreign_key("categories", "users", {:column=>"user_id"})
   -> 0.0021s
```

Which is a problem because the second parameter of update_table_definition (the ... part) is an instance of my migration class and prints 4 screens of text.

Is there a way to get back the simple printout of Rails 5? I know I can turn off migration logs with VERBOSE=false, but then I lose all the migration logs.

The add_reference method and missing_parameter, say_with_time methods (that prints the logs) seemingly didn't change between the two Rails versions.

Comment: This might be better raised at the Rails github issue tracker.  They might well give you a reason for the change and/or fix the problem if it is seen as a bug.